# tmux: how to tell if a pane is currently piped?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'm coming to tmux from screen.  In screen I can see a list of windows (C-a ") and whether or not they are logging.  Flag (L) below indicates logging.  All screen windows below are logged except 4 and 6.

```
Num Name         Flags

   1 [en-x86]      $(L)
   2 [en-ppc]      $(L)
   3 [nms]         $(L)
   4 [scr-4]          $
   5 [scr-5]       $(L)
   6 [scr-6]          $
```

Is there anything similar for pipe pane?  I have a keybind in tmux to log via pipe-pane
`bind-key H pipe-pane -o "exec cat >>$HOME/.tmuxlog/'#S-#I-#W.log'" \; display-message 'Toggled logging to $HOME/.tmuxlog/#S-#I-#W.log'`

but I do not see a way to tell if a pane is currently logging except to type some text in the window then tail the log file.

Answer (score 1):

The `pane_pipe` format variable will be 1 if the pane is being piped but there is nothing that shows this by default (I don't think many people use `pipe-pane` a lot or someone would have asked about before :-). You can do:

```
tmux lsw -F '#{window_index} #{window_name} #{?pane_pipe,piped,not piped}'
```

To show if the current pane in each window is piped. Or similarly with `lsp` for panes, or put it in the status line or whatever as usual with formats.